# Automatically create mock variables in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, mockito

I am a new user of IDEA, coming from Eclipse. My code usually uses Mockito framework for testing.

In Eclipse, I'd always start with  creating the instance under test. Autocompletion of constructor provided me with

```
new Foo(bar, baz, 0, 0);
```

I could then use Ctrl-1 to create fields `bar` and `baz` and add @Mock annotation to them.

IDEA has a different approach to autocompletion. I get

```
new Foo()
```

In more normal environment I could use Ctrl-P and Ctrl-Shift-Space to add arguments. In Mockito-based testing I find myself typing `bar` and `baz`, then using Alt-Enter to create and annotate fields. This seems like more work.

I looked at [Mockito Code Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7901?pr=), but it seems to be guessing at what mocks I need, and not always correctly.

Is there any shortcut that I missed that would create mocks for me? My ideal solution would add something like Ctrl-Shift-M that would work like Ctrl-Shift-Space, but create a mock variable based on function argument name.